# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS mouse flickering

Tags: resolution

I have an HP EliteBook G1 laptop plugged in to an HP docking station.  I also have two Acer 22" monitors plugged in to the HP docking station.  I just got done installing Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and the mouse flickers and sometimes disappears.  This is driving me nutz!

Here is the solution that I've found from all other posts ->
Open System Settings > Displays. In the Displays window, you will see an Unknown monitor. Click it and disable it.﻿

The problem is that I don't have "Unknown monitor" on my display screen to un-check.  Another problem that I am seeing is that once 22" monitor is showing 1680x1050 and the other is 1280x800 and won't increase in screen resolution.

Any ideas?